# How to redirect from a view in one app to a view in another app?

Tags: python, html, django

I have two apps **members** and **ctr**

**member** app handles the login, registration and logout and **ctr** will handle some admin stuff in page named **foradmin.html**.
I want to redirect to from **member/views.py** to **ctr/views.py** after the login has been done.
Please tell me how can I do it

**member/views.py**

```
def loginpage(request):
   if user is not None:
        login(request, user)
            if user.is_superuser:
                return redirect('foradmin')    #this foradmin page is included in ctr urls

@login_required(login_url='login')
@allowed_user(allowed_roles=['admin'])
def foradmin(request):
     return render(request, 'foradmin.html') #I want to redirect this ctr app this is also written in ctr/views.py
```

**member/urls.py**

```
urlpatterns=[
    path('register',views.registerpage, name='register'),
    path('login', views.loginpage, name='login'),
    path('logout', views.logoutUser, name='logout'),
    path('ricktest', views.ricktest, name='ricktest'),
    path('forstaff', views.forstaff, name="forstaff"),
    path('foradmin', views.foradmin, name="foradmin"),
   ]
```

**ctr/views.py**

```
@login_required(login_url='login')
@allowed_user(allowed_roles=['admin'])
def foradmin(request):
     return render(request, 'foradmin.html')
```

**ctr/urls.py**

```
urlpatterns=[
            path('foradmin', views.foradmin, name="foradmin"),
]
```

**Final Note:** I want that after the conditions of login are met this should redirect to ctr app

Comment: Why have you tagged this with PHP??

Comment: oh sorry that was a mistake